# How to add dashes into a number input field while entering the number?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use java script to insert dashes into a html number field at every `4th` digit while entering.I did this in on-blur instead of on-key-press,on-key-up etc.But when I tried to change the function to `on-key-press/on-key-up` events it is not giving the expected results.

This is the code which I used.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function addDashes(f)
 {
   f.value = f.value.slice(0,4)+"-"+f.value.slice(4,8)+"-"+f.value.slice(8,12);
 }
</script>
</head>
  <body>
     Phone: <input type='text' name='phone' onblur='addDashes(this)' maxlength='12'><BR>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am a beginner in 'JavaScript'. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the 'expected results'?

Comment: If I entered 123456789012 then the result should be 1234-5678-9012.

Answer (score 2):

This will work. It also supports 'deletion' of number.

However, I would suggest you using [masking](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtPhoneNo").keyup(function (e) {
      if($(this).val().length === 14) return;
      if(e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 39) return;
      let newStr = '';
      let groups = $(this).val().split('-');
      for(let i in groups) {
       if (groups[i].length % 4 === 0) {
        newStr += groups[i] + "-"
       } else {
        newStr += groups[i];
       }
      }
      $(this).val(newStr);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id="txtPhoneNo" name='phone' maxlength='14'><BR>
```

If you want a snippet of this using masking, let me know, I'll be more than happy to help.

Comment: Updated with a bug fix

Comment: masking is a better option

Comment: If you delete a middle element from the field I think it is disrupting the pattern.Instead of 4-4-3 when you delete from middle it becomes 4-3-4.I prefer your first solution inside the window.onload function.It worked fine for me.

Comment: @KailashPK Are you ok with using 'masking' or you just want to use Jquery to solve the issue?

Comment: @ myke_11j Right now masking is not my first priority,I would like to solve the issue using jquery.Thanks for asking..

Comment: @KailashPK please check the updated answer. Hope it solves your issue

Comment: How to remove the dashes even when i copy paste a value

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla javascript rendition partially inspired by Naman's code with a few more features like deleting and backspacing support.

HTML:

```
<input type="tel" id="phone">
```

Vanilla JS:

```
const phone = document.getElementById('phone');

phone.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if(e.key === "Backspace" || e.key === "Delete") return;
    if(e.target.value.length === 4) {
        phone.value = phone.value + "-";
    }
    if(e.target.value.length === 9) 
        phone.value = phone.value + "-";
    }
    if(e.target.value.length === 14) {
        phone.value = phone.value + "-";
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Give an ID of your textbox and no need of blur function just write this in your document.ready function.
Your HTML line:

```
<input type='text' id="txtPhoneNo" name='phone' maxlength='12'><BR>
```

Your Jquery line:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtPhoneNo").keyup(function () {
                    if ($(this).val().length == 4) {
                        $(this).val($(this).val() + "-");
                    }
                    else if ($(this).val().length == 9) {
                        $(this).val($(this).val() + "-");
                    }
                    else if ($(this).val().length == 14) {
                        $(this).val($(this).val() + "-");
                    }
                });
});
```

hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: This won't work if the user decides to modify early parts (like they typed it all out and realized they missed the second number). They also didn't say anything about jQuery, so I think a vanilla solution would be preferred.

Comment: It is working.But when I try to delete a digit in the middle it's getting messy.Can we do anything about that?

Comment: And one more thing the max length attribute of the field is being taken in another sense there.The hyphens get also counted as a charechtor. The hyphens should be excluded in max length.

Comment: For the length you can count it with hyphens and set it to your textbox maxlength like instead of 12 set it to 19.

Comment: Okay about deleting whatever element you want to delete go at that position using Arrow Key(<-- or -->) and then you can change that element as this is way and it works properly as if you don't want use of Masking and you want to use this code. if you ok with this then can you please upvote this and Mark As Answer.